# Efecto de transición no deseado CSS al cargar la página

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un problema con CSS, quiero colocar una transición de estilos de un elemento en su estado hover, eso funciona, pero también hace la transición al recargar la página o al hacer clic (ya que es un enlace)y no es lo que estoy buscando. Comparto el código.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>ESTILOS CSS</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/logo.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div id="logotipo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo de la web">
            </div>
            <h1>
                <a href="index.html">ESTILOS CSS</a>
            </h1>
        </header>
   
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

style.css

```
#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #70b231;
    font-family: "nevis";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333333;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

#header h1 a {
    color: #70b231;
}

#header h1:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333333, 0px 0px 4px #70b231;
}
```

¿Alguna idea que pueda ayudar?
Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El estado hover debes aplicarlo a `a` y no a `h1` del mismo modo la transición.
El problema con aplicar el hover al h1, es que es funciona como bloque `{display: block}`, entonces el hover te lo aplica a todo el reglón y no solo sobre el texto.

```css
#header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #70b231;
    font-family: "nevis";
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#header h1 a {
    color: #70b231;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333333;
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

#header h1 a:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333333, 0px 0px 4px #70b231;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>ESTILOS CSS</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/logo.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header id="header">
            <div id="logotipo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logotipo de la web">
            </div>
            <h1>
                <a href="index.html">ESTILOS CSS</a>
            </h1>
        </header>
   
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias. Probé de esta forma pero no soluciona el problema, me sigue haciendo la transición al cargar la página, me funcionó al colocar la transición dentro de la pseudo-clase hover, pero tendré un cambio brusco al quitar el hover. Me llama la atención porque estoy siguiendo un tutorial que lo hace tal como lo muestro, y no le pasa lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: Revisa con la edición que acabo de realizar

Comment: Muchas gracias, probé con tu modificación y me sigue pasando lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

De esta forma funciona bien, (pase la transición a la (pseudoClase hover) pero voy a tener un cambio brusco de estilos al quitar el hover, al menos se acerca a lo que busco.

```
#header h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 40px;
        color: #70b231;
        font-family: "nevis";
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333333;
    }

#header h1 a {
    color: #70b231;
}

#header h1:hover a {
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #333333, 0px 0px 4px #70b231;
    transition: all 300ms;
}
```